Case study on inertia
When our upper body and lower body both are in contact with bus then after applying breaks why only upper body part moves forward?

how is the upper body in contact with the bus?

Because friction prevents parts of you to move, but because you are not a rigid body, other parts continue on until tension stops them or you readjust your balance.

using human bodies to understand Newton is never helpful. Consider a system of rods, ideal springs, and masses--and do something quantitative.

The whole body moves forward, but friction between the person's foot and the floor helps keep the relative motion near the foot low.
That being said, as a word from the wise, the human body is an abysmal subject with which to understand Newtonian physics.  The body is full of extremely complex structures and feedback loops that make lots of Newtonian physics somewhere between hard to see and downright counterintuitive.  The effects of inertia are much easier to see with two crates stacked on top of each other.  When the brakes are tapped, those crates will do things that make more sense with respect to the laws of inertia.

Because static friction between the person’s feet and the floor tends to restrain the lower part of the body of a person standing in the bus, while the upper body will tend to move forward if not holding onto something.
Hope this helps.

Assume your feet are on the floor of the bus and your upper body is leaning against a wall in the bus.
Most shoes are designed to be non-slip, so your feet won't move. Also, your feet, ankles and calves don't have much mass, so not much inertia either - there's little force necessary to stop them. This force is supplied by the friction between your shoes and the floor of the bus. As your feet are stationary w.r.t. the bus, they also form a pivot about which your body will rotate.
Most of your mass is in your torso and upper body. This means it also has much more inertia, and a greater force is required to decelerate them. What supplies this force?
If you are just hanging by a strap, your arm has to supply this force. If you are leaning against a wall in the bus, the pressure of your body against the wall must supply this force. Any part of your body not in contact with part of the bus will tend to keep moving forward.
One last thing; your feet are used for walking. That means that they are used to exerting a force against the ground to push you forward and to slow you down. That's what they are designed to do. The rest of your body is not generally used to speed you up and slow you down, so you will be much more aware when that happens. You probably don't notice how your knees are flexing to take the strain.
